# JavaScript: Writing this solution using higher order functions

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I worked on a problem where you are given an array of numbers and a target sum, and it's your job to find a pair of numbers that sum up to the target number. Here was my solution using simple nested for loops:

```
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < integers.length; j++) {

      if (i !== j && integers[i] + integers[j] === target) {
        output.push(integers[i], integers[j]);
        return output;
      }
    }
  }
  return 'not possible';
}

findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 9);  // --> [4, 5]
```

My question is, is there a cleaner way to write this solution using higher order functions (perhaps forEach?)

Here was my attempt to use forEach:

```
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
  var output = [];

  integers.forEach(function(firstNum) {
    integers.forEach(function(secondNum) {

      if (firstNum + secondNum === target) {
        output.push(firstNum, secondNum);
      }
    })
  })

  if (output === []) {
    return 'not possible'; 
  }  
  return output;
}

findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 9); // --> [ 4, 5, 5, 4 ]
```

I tried putting a return after the two pushes, but it did not return anything. So instead, I put the return at the very end.

Why won't it return after the initial two pushes? I want it to stop right there, and only push the two numbers. Instead, by putting the return at the end, it pushed 4 numbers. It should be [4,5] but I got something like [4,5,5,4].

Any advice and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you are doing the same calculations over and over again. Your inside loop should be `for (var j=i+1`

Comment: Advice: use C-style `for` loop.  You want to terminate early for performance reasons because you don't need all combinations.  However, you can't early-terminate the higher-order functions as you can with the C-style for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have the following set of numbers, and we must find a subset of 2 numbers whose sum is `9`:

```
Numbers: 4, 5, 6
```

Your current code iterates both with `i` and `j` from `0` to `length`. This means that the following iterations match the condition:

```
Indices: 0, 1, 2
Numbers: 4, 5, 6   //        (i)          (j)
----------------   //         ↓            ↓
         i  j      // Numbers[0] + Numbers[1] === 9
         j  i      // Numbers[1] + Numbers[0] === 9
```

As you can see, the numbers 4 and 5 are matched twice, in 2 iterations:

- `i === 0 && j === 1`
- `i === 1 && j === 0`

You can avoid this by making sure one simple condition is met:

**`j` must at all times be greater than `i`**

This condition can be met met by initializing `j` with `i + 1` in the inner `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < integers.length; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way, `j` can never be `0` when `i` is `1`, because the inner for-loop will run to completion before `i` is ever incremented once more. Once that happens, a brand new inner for-loop is created, in which `j` is again set to `i + 1`. The following diagram is the result:

```
Indices: 0, 1, 2
Numbers: 4, 5, 6
----------------
         i  j
         X  i     // ← j can never be 0 if (i === 1),
                  //   so the same set is never evaluated twice.
```

In other words, only the following combinations for `i` and `j` are checked at most:

```
Indices: 0, 1, 2
----------------
         i  j
         i     j
            i  j
```

> is there a cleaner way to write this solution using higher order functions (perhaps forEach?)

A for loop is actually a fine solution for your use-case. They allow you to **break early** - after the first time you find a valid pair of numbers. `forEach` or other array iterator functions on the other hand will always continue until all set indices are visited.

*You are actually breaking early in your first example with the statement `return output;`*

When you use `forEach` on a set of numbers with multiple valid sets, you'll always get back all numbers involved:

```
Indices: 0, 1, 2, 3
Numbers: 4, 5, 6, 3    //        (i)          (j)
-------------------    //         ↓            ↓
         i  j          // Numbers[0] + Numbers[1] === 4 + 5 === 9
               i  j    // Numbers[2] + Numbers[3] === 6 + 3 === 9
```

*`forEach`, `map`, `reduce` and the like do not allow you to break early.* The following snippet demonstrates this issue of the diagram above:

```js
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
    var output = [];

    integers.forEach(function(firstNum, i) {
    
        // slice(i + 1) has the same effect as for (var j = i + 1; ...)
        integers.slice(i + 1).forEach(function(secondNum, j) {
        
            if (firstNum + secondNum === target) {
            
                // There is no way here to stop the iteration of either
                // forEach call... T_T
                output.push(firstNum, secondNum);
            }
        });
    })

    if (output.length) {
        return output;
    }

    return 'not possible';
}

console.log(findPairForSum([4, 5, 6, 3], 9)); // --> [4, 5, 6, 3]
```

This is why I highly recommend sticking with the for loops for this specific use case. With for loop you can simply `return` as you already did as soon as you encounter a valid set of numbers:

```js
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < integers.length; j++) {
            if (integers[i] + integers[j] === target) {
                return [integers[i], integers[j]];
            }
        }
    }

    return 'not possible';
}

console.log(findPairForSum([4, 5, 6, 3], 9)); // --> [4, 5]
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this! I learned a lot from reading it. Thank you for taking the time. One question if I may: I don't quite understand where you say I can avoid getting two matches if I use:  j > i , but I do not see where you used that in the code. Is this for the if statement right after the second loop? Thank you so much again for your thorough and insightful answer.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that's kind of vague. I'll update my answer in a minute. Glad to help you out!

Comment: @bax I have updated my answer, and removed the `j > i` notation. It's a short way to say that `j` must always be greater than `i`. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: but if more same numbers, youi return only one pair, not all possible pairs (at least with the last code and for example with this array `[3, 34, 4, 4, 12, 5, 2, 4, 5]`).

Comment: @NinaScholz That's right. This answer assumes that - **(1)** Only one pair of values is required - **(2)** The 2 returned numbers must originate from 2 *distinct* array indices. These are requirements of the question if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you iterate from the start of the array for the inner loop. You could use a copy which starts at the index of the outer loop plus one and exit early on a found value.

But this does not solves the problem with multiple pairs. The result is simply wrong.

```js
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
    var output = [];

    integers.forEach(function(firstNum, i) {
        integers.slice(i + 1).some(function(secondNum) {
            if (firstNum + secondNum === target) {
                output.push(firstNum, secondNum);
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    return output.length && output || 'not possible';
}

//    console.log(findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 2], 9));
console.log(findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 4, 12, 5, 2, 4, 5], 9));
```

For a solution, you need to remember which pairs are used. This approach works with only one loop and a hash table for counting missing values.

If a pair is found, the counter is decremented and the two values are pushed to the result set.

```js
function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        output = [];

    integers.forEach(function(value) {
        if (hash[value]) {
            output.push(target - value, value);
            hash[value]--;
            return;
        }
        hash[target - value] = (hash[target - value] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return output.length && output || 'not possible';
}

console.log(findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 4, 12, 5, 2, 4, 5], 9));
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot looking at this. I really like the some function. I assume the 'return true' after the if statement is so the some function stops execution? Also the final return line was pretty clever. Thank you for answering my question, I learned quite a bit from your answer.

Comment: the accepted answer may not in all cases return the wanted result. anyway. the return in a callback of `forEach` ends the function by using an *exit early paradigm*, which means, a function should if possible use only `if` statements without `else` parts and use return instead. any other following `if` is in an `else` part without using it, because of the *early return*.

Answer (score 1):

This could be your solution:

```js
function findPairForSum(arr, sum) {
  var pairs = [];
  arr.forEach(n1 => {
    var n2 = arr.find(n2 => n1 + n2 == sum)
    if (n2) pairs.push([n1, n2]);
  });
  return pairs;
}


var sums = findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 6, 2], 9);
console.log(sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, since you didn't compare the **indexes**.
This inner array should only loop through the indexes which larger than the outer index.
You can achieve this by using the 2nd parameter, index, in `forEach`'s callback function:

```js
const ints = [3, 34, 4, 12, 5, 6, 2];

function findPairForSum(integers, target) {
  let result;
  integers.forEach((val1, idx1) => {
    integers.forEach((val2, idx2) => {
      if (idx1 < idx2 && val1 + val2 === target) {
        result = [val1, val2];
      }
    })
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(findPairForSum(ints, 9));
```

Comment: This will log `[3, 6, 4, 5]` if we added another `5` to the array.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp Updated. Since it does expect to return more than one pair, and `forEach` does not support `break`. Just return 1 pair should be enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** which will stop execution as soon as the condition becomes true. See below code.

```js
function findPairForSum(arr, sum) {
  var pairs = [];
  arr.some(n1 => {
    var n2 = arr.find(n2 => n1 + n2 == sum)
    if (n2) {
      pairs.push(n1, n2); return true;
    };
    return false;
  });
  return pairs.length > 0 ? pairs : "not possible"; 
}
console.log(findPairForSum([3, 34, 4, 12, 7, 2], 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can `reduce` your array into another which has sum equals target `value`:

```js
const ints = [3, 34, 4, 12, 6, 2];
const value = 9;

const resp = ints.reduce((acc, ele, idx, self) => {
  let found = self.find(x => x + ele == value)
  return found ? [found, ele] : acc;
}, []);

console.log(resp); // [3, 6]
```